# NetBean and Websphere 8.5

Tags: java, netbeans, websphere, hotswap, dynamic-class-loaders

We recently migrated our Mavenized Java application to Netbean.
Backend is websphere 8.5.5 FP 18.
We deploy our application as a single EAR file comprising JAR and WAR

We configured WAS to run in development mode and our application to detect class file changes to reload every 3 seconds.

When Web java codes is changed by adding a print line, the class is reloaded automatically.  We can see the changes.  But this is not possible when we add a print line to a method in the EJB.

We get this message on Netbean.

```
Classes to reload:
com.example.sb.SB_User_permissionBean$1
com.example.sb.SB_User_permissionBean

The virtual machine does not support this operation: changes to class modifiers not implemented
```

Would appreciate any direction.

CS

Comment: [1] I can't help with your question, but it would be helpful to update it with the versions of NetBeans, JDK and Java EE that are being used. [2] I was unaware that you could even run WebSphere within NetBeans. Are you doing that [using this plugin](https://github.com/tjmcmanus/NetbeansLibertyPlugin)? If not, how are you doing it?

Comment: @skomisa, nothing special actually.  On Netbean, we opened the maven project, attached the debugger.  On WAS console, we set it to development and enable debugging.  On the enterprise application, we configure class reloading every 3 seconds.  Using Apache NetBeans IDE 12.3.